# How to write startup logic which does not create a bean to run during spring configuration lifecycle?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In addition to traditional beans that were configuring with @configuration and @bean we have some startup logic in our code which must be done at bootup, things like running liquibase on the database, loading configuration data from files into database, and performing some sanity tests.  None of this is really associated with a Bean that will autowired afterwards, the changes are being persisted via the database not spring.  However, there is a good amount of it to be done.  Much of it is also dependent on earlier steps having completed and/or services being autowired.

What is the best way to do this within a spring context?  I know that there is an ApplicationContextAware we could use to start this logic, but it doesn't seem appropriate because of a few reasons

1. it would run an applicationcontext refresh, not just at bootup
2. This would allow running just one class, I'd prefer to be able to write logic the way we do @configuration where I can toss in a new component and have it run where appropriate
3. In at least one case we have a bean that we can't properly configure until some of the database configuration is done, meaning we want this configuration logic to run in the middle of the spring bootup, not at the end.

Currently the approach we have is a @Configuration class that has no @bean method, instead using afterPropertiesSet() to run a database configuration file that sequentially goes through each database configuration phase in a large configure method.  This does work pretty well, but it feels like it's breaking the intended use of @configuration to be used explicitly for creating @bean definitions for later autowiring.

Does spring provide a better approach for being able to plus non-bean configuration into the middle of it's configuration/autowire phase, or is this the best approach available?

To answer the question in the comment this is a restful web application using spring-mvc.  It's a war started when the web server is started.

Comment: In what context are you using spring? Is it a web application, stand alone application? How is the application started? You are asking about application initialization, you need to give more detail about that aspect.

Comment: Have you tried writing that as a part of ApplicationContextInitializer , which runs before spring context starts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having similar requirements where I wanted to fetch the Records from DB and put it into my Cache whenever my Server starts and I achieved it by writing a method in my Service Class and annotating it as `@PostConstruct`. What will happen is that once the Bean Creation is done then this method will execute and it will execute only once after the bean creation or during the Server Startup.

It is very simple as you need not to write a separate class and you can do it simply by creating an additional method in your Controller/Service Class.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Interface ApplicationContextInitializer to cater this need

From Spring Docs

> public interface ApplicationContextInitializer
>
> Callback interface for initializing a Spring
>   ConfigurableApplicationContext prior to being refreshed.
>
> Typically used within web applications that require some
>   programmatic initialization of the application context. For example,
>   registering property sources or activating profiles against the
>   context's environment. See ContextLoader and FrameworkServlet support
>   for declaring a "contextInitializerClasses" context-param and
>   init-param, respectively.

Comment: I need our logic to run after some beans are configured, but before other beans are.  As I understand  the ApplicationContextInitalizer it can't be run in the middle of the configuration phase like that, can it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure thing.

If you have Config class annotated with `@Configration` you can just put the any init logic into the method annotated it with appropriate `@PostConstruct` annotation.

Or even more: create the method with void return type and put your logic there. 
For example:

```
@Autowire
void init() {
   // some logic goes here
}
```